# How to send a submission via ajax in php

Tags: php, ajax

I posted this item that has several active class choices

```js
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).on('click', '#btnkharid2', function(e){
       var idservice = [];
    $('.rowemkanat.activeservic').each(function(i, selected){
            idservice[i] = $(selected).attr('id');
    });

    $.ajax({
      url  : '<?= URL ?>nm/finishkharid',
      type : 'POST',
      data:{'idservice[]':idservice},
```

```html
<div class="active"></div>
<div class=""></div>
<div class="active"></div>
```

How to get in php?

How do I get this presentation when the idea is equal to that table?

```html
  function finishkharid22($data,$setname)
  {
  $idser = $data['idservice'];

  $sql="SELECT * from `tbl_services` where id=? ";
                    $result=self::$db->prepare($sql);
                    $result->bindparam(1, $deidser);
                    $result->execute();
                    $resqs=$result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

use F12 network or console tab to see your errors or do you get any response from php code. `var_dump($_POST)` in your php, to see if you pass your data to php file via `$.ajax`.

i think this should be service ID - `$idser = $data['idservice'];`

BUT, to SQL query you bind `$desider` variable `$result->bindparam(1, $deidser);`

**EDIT**

Your code:

```
var idservice = [];
    $('.rowemkanat.activeservic').each(function(i, selected){
            idservice[i] = $(selected).attr('id');
    });
data:{'idservice[]':idservice}
```

After loop, where you assign new values to `idservice` array, you can `console.log(idservice);` to test do you have what you want in your array before you pass it to php with ajax. When you pass variables via ajax, i think it should be like this:

```
data:{'idservice':idservice}
```

not this:

```
data:{'idservice[]':idservice}
```

In PHP code:

```
var_dump($_POST['idservice']);
```

Some info for adding values to JS array - [W3](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp#:%7E:text=The%20push()%20method%20adds,use%20the%20unshift()%20method.)

Comment: Thank you. I have no problem with sending, I just gave a better explanation in the new post. Take another look, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but my problem is exactly where I want several items to be selected together

I am sending this item

```js
     var idservice = [];
        $('.rowemkanat.activeservic').each(function(i, selected){
                idservice[i] = $(selected).attr('id');
        });
    data:{'idservice[]':idservice},
```

how do I get this array in php

I wrote it myself
And when I say with a query that these ids were sent, make the bet, but it will come back again.

```html
function finishkharid22($data,$setname)
{
foreach ($data['idservice'] as $item) {
        $items=$item;

    }
        $sql="SELECT * from `tbl_services` where id=? ";
        $result=self::$db->prepare($sql);
        $result->bindparam(1, $deidser);
        $result->execute();
        $resqs=$result->fetchAll();
        foreach ($resqs as $items) {
          $serviceid=$item2['id'];
          $servicename=$item2['title'];
          var_dump($servicename);
      }
}
```

I want the ids of that table to return the result with the ids that are sent